# Familiar Acquaintance

Tags: riddle

Few, if any, see me coming,
Odds have it that we've met.
I can show myself as friend or foe,
As relief or as competition,
I never do the same thing a lot,
For when I do I cease to be.
I've been the downfall of wise men
And the best friend of simple ones.
I have no feelings but can be happy, so tell me,
You, who is full of wit,
Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> An accident

Few, if any, see me coming,

> If it were predictable, it wouldn't be an accident, now would it?

Odds have it that we've met.

> Everyone has had *something* happen to them by accident

I can show myself as friend or foe,
As relief or as competition,

> Accidents can be positive or negative, harmful or beneficial

I never do the same thing a lot,
For when I do I cease to be.

> The same accident happening over and over again is not an accident, but a pattern with a cause.

I've been the downfall of wise men
And the best friend of simple ones.

> An accident can cause the mighty to be brought low, and lift up the lowest

I have no feelings but can be happy, so tell me,

> Remember, we don't have mistakes here, only happy accidents!

You, who is full of wit,

> I will just point out here that on initial reading, I read: full of...well, something that rhymes with wit

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> Luck

Few, if any, see me coming,

> Luck is mostly blind luck so you don't seeing it coming.  But relatively few people (*i.e.* those in the know, people who understand the mathematical probabilities involved very well, *etc*) do see it coming.

Odds have it that we've met.

> A play on the word  *odds* and everybody's either lucky or unlucky at some point in their life.

I can show myself as friend or foe,

> Sometimes you're lucky and sometimes you're not.

As relief or as competition,

> You can be lucky if something good has happened or unlucky if something bad.

I never do the same thing a lot,

> Luck entails randomness so it has to vary.

For when I do I cease to be.

> Because when it's predictable it's not luck anymore.

I've been the downfall of wise men

> Many tales of wise men losing it all through bad luck (*i.e.* going bankrupt through unlucky bets).

And the best friend of simple ones.

> But some people, with no concept at all of the odds against them, win huge windfalls.

I have no feelings but can be happy...

> Pure luck is based on a mathematical model, so no feelings are involved.  But can be "Happy go lucky".

...,so tell me,
You, who is full of wit,
Who am I?

> If I'm *lucky* I got it right! :) )

Comment: Close, real close, but no dice (ha ha). The line "I can be happy"  refers directly to whoever is  speaking and not to any user of it.